# Calculate in React Form

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am trying to create a custom pricing form. In which the buyer will be able to choose different options. And each option will have a associated price. After choosing the options the form will automatically show the total price. I am using GatsbyJS.

```
<form>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Beaf</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="50 USD" checked />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Cheap Beaf
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="100 USD" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
        Expensive Beaf
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Cheese</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="40 USD" checked />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Cheap Cheese
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="80 USD" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
        Expensive Cheese
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Bread</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1" value="30 USD" checked />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
        Cheap Bread
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2" value="60 USD" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
        Expensive Bread
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label>Total Price</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Readonly input here…" readonly />
</form>
```

Comment: You need to store selected (price/value) in state and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using react state with hooks. You need to use react state for this and change the price on onChange event. I just made a quick prototype for you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-calculate-in-react-form-dum7k?file=/src/App.tsx

You only need to set prices for defaultChecked products in on component mount. It can be achieved with useEffect.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sodhi for creating a prototype for me using your valuable time. Your code is great but I do need to calculate the prices together. Example: Cheap Beaf + Expensive Cheese + Cheap Bread = Total Price.

Comment: updated answer and above link. Please check it :)

Comment: THANKS AGAIN. It looks like you worked on it for more than half an hour. Really appreciate your effort. But it looks like it doesn't start calculating until you change a single option.

Comment: You need to calculate initial total and then calculate onChange.

Comment: Type Annotations can only be used in typescript files. I am getting this error. Any way to use it without typescript?

Comment: feel free to use it without TS. Main thing to understand the logic behind it.

Comment: On line 15 it is showing an error regarding typescript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226788/discussion-between-sodhi-saab-and-lily-nicole-talmers).

Comment: Looks like the calculator is miscalculating. Sent you an email on freecodehelp@gmail.com